# Stochastic integral of indicator function with respect to geometric Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I have been having trouble solving/simplifying this stochastic integral: $$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\int_0^T 1_{\{S_t>K\}}dS_t)$$ where $dS=rSdt+\sigma SdW$. What is the best way to approach this?

$\textbf{Attempted Solution:}$

$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\int_0^T 1_{\{S_t>K\}}dS_t)$$
$$=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\int_0^T 1_{\{S_t>K\}}(rS_t dt+\sigma S_t dW_t))$$
$$=\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\int_0^T 1_{\{S_t>K\}}rS_t dt)+\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\int_0^T 1_{\{S_t>K\}}\sigma S_t dW_t)$$
Then exchanging the expectation and the first integral assuming basic regularity conditions
$$=\int_0^T r \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(1_{\{S_t>K\}}S_t) dt+\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\int_0^T 1_{\{S_t>K\}}\sigma S_t dW_t)$$
Then using the known moments of a truncated log-normal random variable, the expectation is equal to:
$$=\int_0^T r S_0 e^{(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t} \Phi(\frac{(r+\sigma^2)t-ln(K/S_0)}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 t}}) dt+\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\int_0^T 1_{\{S_t>K\}}\sigma S_t dW_t)$$
Finally the second integral is equal to zero as $\int_0^T 1_{\{S_t>K\}}\sigma S_t dW_t$ is a martingale on $[0,T]$, and therefore the expecation of it is zero.  Therefore:
$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\int_0^T 1_{\{S_t>K\}}dS_t)=\int_0^T r S_0 e^{(r+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t} \Phi(\frac{(r+\sigma^2)t-ln(K/S_0)}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 t}}) dt$$

Is all of that correct?

Comment: What's $Z$? Actually, the second integral is $\int_0^T 1_{\{S_t>K\}}\sigma S_t dW_t$, it has zero expectation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $W$, not $Z$ for the edit.  It's fixed.  Why does that have zero expectation?  I know $W_t$ is a zero mean process, but how does that imply the whole second integral is zero?

Comment: This is a standard property of Ito integral.

Comment: Seems correct now. Another comment: by Tanaka formula, the expression in question is $(S_T-K)^+ - (S_0-K)^+ - \frac{\sigma^2 K^2}2 L(T,K)$, where $L$ is the local time of $S$ at $K$ on $[0,T]$. From here, it is possible to get an alternative expression for the expectation (somewhat simpler probably, as there would be $\phi$, not $\Phi$ under the integral).

Comment: Probably, this would be precisely the same expression one would get integrating by parts in your last formula.